# How to make a post call to insert into database with an array of object in Express JS. Can some one helppp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using ExpressJS for serverside. Whenever making a post call with single object in an array everything is working fine. but when there are multiple objects in array then im getting this error:

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

this is the object:

```
 selectedItems: [
    { id: '1', pipeId: 3, heatId: '1111', idNo: '1' },
    { id: '1', pipeId: 4, heatId: '1111', idNo: '2' },
    { id: '4', pipeId: 6, heatId: '1111', idNo: '4' },
    { id: '5', pipeId: 5, heatId: '1111', idNo: '5' }
  ],
```

this is my post call:

```
function saveLoadDetails(requestBody, res) {
  console.log(requestBody);
  let countOfSelectedItems = requestBody.selectedItems.length;
  let dDate = new Date();
  var out = {};
  let currentDate = moment(dDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  console.log(date + "uploadLoadDetails fired");
  for (let i = 0; i <= countOfSelectedItems - 1; i++) {
    const request = new sql.Request(dbconn1);
    request.input("loadNo", sql.Int, requestBody.loadNumber);
    request.input("loadedOn", sql.VarChar, currentDate);
    request.input("pipeId", sql.NVarChar, requestBody.selectedItems[i].pipeId);
    request.input("heatNo", sql.NVarChar, requestBody.selectedItems[i].heatId);
    request.input("uid_ent", sql.VarChar, requestBody.uid_ent);
    request.execute("mobile_save_shipping_load_details", (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        out = {
          code: 200,
          status: "OK",
          message: "pipe saved",
          data: {
            result,
          },
        };
      } else {
        out = {
          code: 404,
          status: " DB Error : Data Operation Failed.",
          data: { err },
        };
      }
      res.send(out);
    });
  }

  console.log(out);
  sendEmail(requestBody);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs whenever you try to send more than one response, your `res.send ()` is inside a callback inside a loop, that is, several objects in the array are equivalent to several responses.

https://www.nodejsconnect.com/blog/articles/sending-multiple-http-responses-expressjs